# Confidence Interval from LOESS dissapears when using weights with geom_smooth command

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

In R, using the ggplot2 package, I have these two lines:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = Pinera)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 1) + 
    geom_smooth(method = loess, se = TRUE)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = Pinera, weight = pesos)) + 
    geom_point(shape = 1) + 
    geom_smooth(method = loess, se = TRUE)
```

The first one gives me an unweighted smooth curve from my data with the shaded confidence interval, however when I add the weights, the confidence interval region disappears despite I stated `se = TRUE`.

This is my [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ZaIr0rsdeiQ2lISHlSWUVXcFk)

Comment: your data doesnt seem to have a pesos variable

Comment: I created locally in the code the pesos variable using x. I already figured out the problem: when created the "pesos", some weights were rounded to 0, which are not accepted in the model.

By imposing at least an epsilon for every weight it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved: loess cannot process weight vectors with zeros.